# Autocomplete list on top of fixed navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-autocomplete

In order to make a fixed `navbar` containing a search `<input>` element that is querying Google location API to get a list of address I did this:

```
<nav id="inforisq-navbar" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div id="menu-inforisq" class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse collapse">
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img src="/portail/images/logo_inforisq_2015.png" height="40"></a>
        </div>

        <div id="search-container" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input name="searchbar" id="searchbar" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="on" value="" placeholder="Saisissez une adresse postale ou des coordonnées GPS.">
                        <div class="input-group-addon"><a id="validation" onclick="validSearch();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">
            <li><a href="#" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" role="button">MyInforisq <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="drop2">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span>
                </a>
                <ul id="dropdown-services" aria-labelledby="drop2" class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span><span class="services-class">Etat des risques</span></li>
                    <li><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></span><span class="services-class">Renseignements d'urbanisme</span></li>
                    <li><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span><span class="services-class">Etude d'opportunité</span></li>
                    <li><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></span><span class="services-class">Valeur vénale</span></li>
                    <li><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span><span class="services-class">Audit de parc immobilier</span></li>
                    <li><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span><span class="services-class">Hypothèques</span></li>
                    <li><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span><span class="services-class">Plan de réseau</span></li>
                    <li><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span><span class="services-class">Diagnostics immobiliers</span></li>
                    <li><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span><span class="services-class">Expertises immobilières</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And here is the result :

[image]

As you can see, the autocomplete list is behind the fixed `navbar` and I wanted to know how to put it above in css.

[SOLUTION]

Only have to add z-index > 1030 as : `.pac-container{ z-index: 1031;}`

Comment: Also better if you could create a demo here in **Snippet**.

Comment: searchbar have a z-index property

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your css looks like, but you could try adding a z-index on your auto-complete list.

```
.autoCompleteList{
z-index:300;
}
```